# log4j info level & debug not working

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I am using log4j in a spring application. The bean creation & other information is being displayed correctly in the console & written on the disk but in the handler method the 
log.info & log.debug are not working. I see no output in the console. Can anyone tell me why?

log4j.properties

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c \u2013 %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout
```

ClinicController.java

```
package com.petclinic.controller;


//ClinicController is the generic controller for the web app
@Controller
public class ClinicController {

    @Autowired
    private ClinicService clinicService;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("ClinicController");


    //Custom Handler for the welcome Page
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcomeHandler(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        logger.info(request.getServletPath());
        System.out.println("Inside Welcome Controller");
        System.out.println(request.getServletPath());
        logger.debug("Inside Clinic Controller Welcome Controller");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

I can see System.out statements in the console but not logger.info & debug.

```
logger.info(request.getServletPath());
logger.debug("Inside Clinic Controller Welcome Controller");
```

Am I missing something?

log snippet

```
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0135 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping – Matching patterns for request [/welcome.jsp] are [/welcome.*]
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0143 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping – Mapping [/welcome.jsp] to handler 'com.petclinic.controller.ClinicController@dd02e8'
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0152 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet – Last-Modified value for [/PetClinic/forms/welcome.jsp] is: -1
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0163 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet – DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/PetClinic/forms/welcome.jsp]
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0193 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker – Invoking request handler method: public java.lang.String com.petclinic.controller.ClinicController.welcomeHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
Inside Welcome Controller
/forms
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0199 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory – Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'welcome'
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0200 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet – Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/welcome.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0211 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView – Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0278 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet – Successfully completed request
2014-02-26 00:02:32.0280 DEBUG "http-bio-8080"-exec-7 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter – Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
```

Comment: Why do you set the logger level twice? `log4j.rootLogger=debug, info` debug should allow info as well, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Where is your log4j.properties file located? As you build a WAR, your log4j.properties file should be in the root of the WEB-INF/classes folder.

2.) As suggested by archie hicox, you should change rootlogger to log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout (without info)

Comment: Yes it was originally `log4j.rootLogger=debug, file, stdout (without info)` I added info for just checking. The log4j properties file is in the src classpath folder. I believe the properties file is in the correct folder that's why the other logs are being generated in the console.

Comment: If so, please open your JAR with a zip-tool and check if the file is located under WEB-INF/classes. If you use any appserver connected with your IDE, go to the deployment-folder and check if the file is in the correct location. Information about your system environment may help ;)

Comment: tried with replacing log4j 2 jar file with 1.2 version. Working now. I believe log4j 2 might have some subtle difference in configuration.